# Using Azure Redis Cache with Node.js (for Hubot's brain)?

Tags: azure, redis, node-redis, hubot, azure-redis-cache

I am trying to use Azure Redis Cache as the storage for my Hubot's brain.

I have followed the instructions [here](https://github.com/hubot-scripts/hubot-redis-brain) to configure the Redis brain.  I have also tried both SSL and unencrypted connections, as I read [here](https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis/issues/650) that the Redis Node client does not support SSL.

I also updated the Redis client in my `hubot-redis-brain` from `0.8.4` to `2.6.2`, but my Hubot is still unable to connect to Redis.

Here is a screen shot of the port config in Azure:

[image]

And this is the output when my Hubot starts:

```
[Fri Sep 23 2016 09:00:14 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)] INFO hubot-redis-brain: Discovered redis from REDISTOGO_URL environment variable
node_redis: Deprecated: The AUTH command contains a "undefined" argument.
This is converted to a "undefined" string now and will return an error from v.3.0 on.
Please handle this in your code to make sure everything works as you intended it to.
[Fri Sep 23 2016 09:00:21 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)] ERROR hubot-redis-brain: Failed to authenticate to Redis
[Fri Sep 23 2016 09:00:21 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)] ERROR ReplyError: Ready check failed: NOAUTH Authentication required.
  at parseError (C:\projects\hubot-tryout\node_modules\redis-parser\lib\parser.js:163:12)
  at parseType (C:\projects\hubot-tryout\node_modules\redis-parser\lib\parser.js:224:14)
```

Any help on this would be much appreciated.

**UPDATE**

This is the code I'm using to connect unencrypted:

```
client = Redis.createClient("6379", "my-host.redis.cache.windows.net" , { auth_pass: "access-key" } )
```

And this for the encrypted connection:

```
client = Redis.createClient("6380", "my-host.redis.cache.windows.net" , { auth_pass: "access-key" } ), tls: {servername: 'my-host.redis.cache.windows.net'} })
```

Comment: Also chewing on that one.

Answer (score 0):

I would try URL encoding the password.  I wonder if you are running into the same problem that is described here for using Azure Redis for PHP Session...

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cache-faq/#can-i-use-azure-redis-cache-as-a-php-session-cache

Comment: Thanks Jon.  I tried encoding the password with `encodeURIComponent()`, but I get back an `ERROR ReplyError: ERR invalid password` error now.

Comment: From our internal testing it looks like URL encoding **IS NOT required** when using the `{ auth_pass: "access-key" }` approach.  

URL encoding of just the password **IS required** when using the `"redis://urlEncodedPass@contoso.redis.cache.windows.net:6379"` approach

Comment: Thanks Jon.  Do you have it working in a vanilla Node app and with Hubot?